# How does S3 get permission from Lambda trigger?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I'm working out the security details for working with Lambda. One thing I can't find out is how S3 gets permission to push to Lambda when you add a trigger from the Lambda console or via S3 - Properties - Events. I know how it works using the CLI and I know you could do it via the SDK but I also noticed it isn't always necessary. Mostly the trigger just 'works' without me adding any permissions. Does anybody know why?

And is there a way to find out what Permissions S3/an S3 bucket has? I know there's a tab 'Permissions' but that's not giving me any information. I also know about Truster Advisor but that's just telling me there's no explicit problem with the permissions. I'm wondering if I can get a list of permissions though?

I hope someone can help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: The steps for configuring S3 to publish events to Lambda are documented at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-configure-event-source.html

Comment: Thank you captain obvious :p that wasn't the question.

Comment: That document also explains the permissions/trust that the S3 service principal has to invoke your Lambda function (whether you explicitly provided that permission or the AWS condole implicitly created it in response to you adding an event trigger).

Comment: I know but it still doesn't explain why I get the error sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a trigger in the console is the equivalent of [assigning permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/add-permission.html) and setting a [bucket notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-notification-configuration.html). You can see the policy associated with a particular lambda function by using the [`get-policy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-policy.html) cli command:

```
aws lambda get-policy --function-name <name>
```

This will tell you what the policy is for your function. Including the resources with rights to invoke it. This policy isn't applied to the S3 bucket, but instead your lambda function.

You can also see what your bucket is set up to notify in the console under **Properties > Events** or review this with the cli using the [`get-bucket-notification`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-bucket-notification.html) command:

```
aws s3api get-bucket-notification --bucket <bucket>
```

Comment: That's what I thought at first, adding a trigger in the console is actually assigining the permissions. But if that's true, do you have any idea why it sometimes happen that when I add a trigger and try to save, I get an error because the S3 bucket doesn't have permission to push to Lambda?

Do you mean by the policy for my function the policies that are in the role the function uses? 

Thanks so much for your answers! Sometimes you just keep thinking in circles.

Comment: You'd have to let me know exactly what the error says. I haven't experienced that. S3 doesn't need any special permissions to push the notifications to Lambda on it's side. Lambda consumes an object that is sent assuming the Lambda permissions allow invocation. If it doesn't, S3 will send the notification and nothing will happen. This _may_ get logged in Cloudtrail if its missing invocation rights, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't have a screenshot of the error but textwise it's the same as this:
`{ [InvalidArgument: Unable to validate the following destination configurations]
  message: 'Unable to validate the following destination configurations',
  code: 'InvalidArgument',
  time: Mon Jun 22 2015 12:48:26 GMT+0300 (EEST),
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 30 }`
And I read over here that it has something to do with not adding the right permissions to S3: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=182758

Comment: It sounds like that is saying you cant add a notification without the Lambda policy, which is likely true. However through the console the console states "Lambda will add the necessary permissions for Amazon S3 to invoke your Lambda function from this trigger" so I'm not quite sure why that would fail for you.

Comment: Perhaps it's a fluke, I really don't know. Most times it works fine too so I'm not sure. Thank you very much for your help! It's helped me see the greater picture again.